# How to apply a function to multiple columns of a data frame aggregated by some other columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

I have a data frame `df` with four columns, e.g.

```
A  B  C  D
x  a  1  3
x  a  3  4
x  b  5  5
x  b  6  8
y  a  6  5
y  a  8  9
y  b  7  0
y  b  4  2
```

I want to aggregate this data frame by columns A and B and then to apply a function for each group on the columns C and D. One such function might be `cor`, another `lm`. The result should look like

```
A  B  cor/lm.coef
x  a  ...    
x  b  ...
y  a  ...
y  b  ...
```

I have found one way to come closer to the desired result: by the function `by`:

```
by(df, c("A", "B"), function(x) cor(x$C, x$D))
by(df, c("A", "B"), function(x) lm(C ~ D, data = x))
```

My questions: Can I extract the desired result as a new data frame where `cor` resp. `lm.coef` is indexed by the factors of columns A and B? How can I access the result object of `by`? Is there another way to get the desired result at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not a big fan of `by()`. I'd tackle this task with `split()` and `lapply()`.

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, list(df$A, df$B)),
   function(d) {
      l <- lm(C~D, data=d)$coef
      data.frame(A=d$A[1], B=d$B[1], COR=cor(d$C, d$D), LM1=l[1], LM2=l[2])
   }
))
```

This gives:

```
    A B COR       LM1        LM2
x.a x a   1 -5.000000  2.0000000
y.a y a   1  3.500000  0.5000000
x.b x b   1  3.333333  0.3333333
y.b y b  -1  7.000000 -1.5000000
```

By the way, the object returned by `by()` is in fact a matrix:

```
x <- by(df, list(df$A, df$B), function(x) cor(x$C, x$D))
unclass(x)
#   a  b
# x 1  1
# y 1 -1
```

This may give you a hint on how to process it further on.

Comment: All four answers work as expected, thanks to all. This one is accepted because it does not require an extra package and it list the grouping factors A and B explcitely. Of course the other answers solve the problem perfectly too.

Answer (score 2):

Just to complement @gagolews answer, here is a `dplyr` version

```
txt <- 'A  B  C  D
x  a  1  3
x  a  3  4
x  b  5  5
x  b  6  8
y  a  6  5
y  a  8  9
y  b  7  0
y  b  4  2'
df <- read.table(text = txt, header = TRUE)


library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(A, B) %>%
  do(mod = lm(C ~ D, data = .), cor = with(., cor(C, D))) %>%
  do(data_frame(
      A = .$A,
      B = .$B,
      cor = .$cor,
      lm1 = coef(.$mod)[1],
      lm2 = coef(.$mod)[2])
     )

##   A B cor     lm1      lm2
## 1 x a   1 -5.0000  2.00000
## 2 x b   1  3.3333  0.33333
## 3 y a   1  3.5000  0.50000
## 4 y b  -1  7.0000 -1.50000
```

Answer (score 2):

A `data.table` approach would be:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[,c(as.list(coef(lm(C~D))), list(cor = cor(C, D))), by=.(A,B)]
```

The `c` is used to combine/concentrate the two lists: `as.list(coef(...))` and `list(cor = ...)`. `data.table` automaticalls makes them columns.

Results in:

```
   A B (Intercept)          D cor
1: x a   -5.000000  2.0000000   1
2: x b    3.333333  0.3333333   1
3: y a    3.500000  0.5000000   1
4: y b    7.000000 -1.5000000  -1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Expanding on your solution
x2<-df
#your code
mycor<-with(x2,by(x2[,3:4],interaction(A,B),cor))
myreg<-with(x2,by(x2,interaction(A,B),function(x)lm(C~D,data=x)))

#extra line
myreg_coef<-do.call(rbind,lapply(unique(interaction(x2$A,x2$B)),
        function(x) cbind(group=x,corr=mycor[[x]][2],t(data.frame(myreg[[x]][1])))))
```